# How to read parameters parsed to a javascript file

Tags: javascript

I have a js script file being loaded async from a function inside an html file. This has been done in a way which make me out of control of any `<script>` id, which mean I am NOT able to use getElementById. 
The script file being loaded is:

```
<path to file>/my_script.js?name=23
```

What I would like to do is to parse the 'name' inside the script file at the moment the file is being loaded. I have full control over the script file but no control over the html file.
Is it possible for the script to get hold in this name - not using getElementById or getElementByName?

Comment: Tbh I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: You could add the entire tag to the post, but most likely you need a reference to the currently running script: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript . If you need to support IE, use [`document.scripts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scripts) collection.

Comment: I am trying to read the parameter 'name' inside the my_script.js file

Comment: @PerMikkelsen you would have to store the `name` globally in the `window` object somewhere inside this function in the document. Or the server would have to take the name and somehow include it in the response, that means in the script which is returned.